# Aot-full compilation in Mono for iOs

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there any way to use stock mono and compile to iOs using `--aot=full` ?

I am aware of Xamarin, but I'm looking for a free solution, since I'm looking for an automated way to test some AOT-specific bugs in a FOSS project.

I know that Unity uses an executable `mono-xcompiler` in order to do that, but I couldn't find out how this executable is compiled from the mono code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. You need to compile mono in cross-compilation mode. The configure arguments in my machine (64-bit Linux) were the following:

```
CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --target=arm-darwin11 --host=i686-linux --enable-system-aot --with-sgen=no
```

We need to compile as 32-bit since mono cannot generate an ARM build from a 64-bit executable; Also, sgen was causing trouble with the TLS mode. It may be possible to overcome this, but I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative might be to apply for an Open Source Project Xamarin license: http://resources.xamarin.com/open-source-contributor.html